# How do I render a Zend_View script from a string instead of a file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, view

I currently have a CMS that writes some pages in a database table.  In order to render them with Zend_View I have a method that writes them to the filesystem.  I'd like to skip that process and render the templates directly from the database.

For example:

```
<?php
$template = '<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->test ?>
</body>
</html>';

$view = new Zend_View();
$view->test = 'This is a test';
echo $view->render($template);
?>
```

Comment: Isnt this working as expected?

Comment: No, this does not work by default. Zend_View_Abstract::render must be passed a file name. A Zend_View_Exception with message "script '<html> ...' not found in path..." will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

`Zend_View` extends `Zend_View_Abstract` and declares a concrete implementation of the `_run()` method (which is invoked by `render()`). sic:

```
protected function _run()
{
    include func_get_arg(0);
}
```

I guess what you want is basically:

```
class Zend_View_String extends Zend_View // or maybe // extends Zend_View_Abstract
{
    protected function _run()
    {
        $php = func_get_arg(0);

        eval(' ?>'. $php. '<?php ');
    }
}
```

But that might be slower than writing it to a file and calling `include`. You can put your file dumping code inside your own `_run` method instead. Doing so is left as an exercise for the reader.